# when templating the inheritance of a class, how to keep it generic?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, stl

Sorry if my English or my coding conventions are bad. 
std::list is the STL list.
I am trying to make a library that will use `std::list<>::iterator` and `std::list<>::reverse_iterator` seamlessly to the user according to his choice.
First, I wouldn't like to implement all `std::list<>::iterator` methods. So I'll inherit them to my class:

```
template <class realIter> class directedListTypeIter : public realIter
```

The user will instantiate the directedListTypeIter with 2 possible templates:

```
directedListTypeIter<std::list<value>::iterator>
directedListTypeIter<std::list<value>::reverse_iterator>
```

It means that I should create the following assignment operators (or copy constructor):

```
directedListTypeIter& operator=(std::list<value>::reverse_iterator &constructorIter) {
   ((std::list<value>::reverse_iterator*)this)->operator=(constructorIter);
   return *this;
}

directedListTypeIter& operator=(std::list<value>::iterator &constructorIter){
   ((std::list<value>::reverse_iterator*)this)->operator=(constructorIter);
   return *this;
}
```

I need all this assignment operators for the following function implementation, and other similar implementations.

```
directedListTypeIter begin(std::list<value>& userList){ 
  directedListTypeIter<realIter> retVal;
  if (someCheck()){
    retVal = userList.begin();
  } else {
    retVal = userList.rbegin();
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

In different words- In order to implement the begin() function, and other similar functions I need, I should implement the assignment operator (or copy constructor).

Here is my questions:

i. All this depends on the existence and usage of the "value" struct. How can I remove this dependency?

ii. If I had more possible **inherited types**, should I have been creating new assignment operator (or copy constructor) for each type? isn't the template programming meant not to copy that code? How can I make the same without copying the code to each operator?

iii. What should I add so the following:

```
 directedListTypeIter& operator=(realIter &constructorIter){
   ((realIter*)this)->operator=(constructorIter);
   return *this;
 }
```

would compile- without adding something that lists all possible inherited values?

Thank you.

p.s. This topic is about how to template the inheritance, and not about achieving the use of both iterator types in one interface. I mean- the "C++ Standard Library list" use case is just an example to better explain my issue.

Comment: There is a bunch of code fragments with incorrect and inconsistent syntax. Can you show something that compiles?

Comment: @MarkB: if you have edited this, please revert, the new state is in no way better than the original one.

Comment: So your `directedTypeListIterator` can either be a reverse_iterator or a normal iterator? There's an [iterator adapter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) in the Std to create `reverse_iterators` from any sort of iterators, even user-defined.

Comment: Is it necessary to derive from the StdLib iterator types? Why not wrap them (as data members)?

Comment: Your design of `begin` sadly will not work.

That's because `std::list<X>::iterator` and `std::list<X>::reverse_iterator` are distinct, unrelated types. So are your `directedListTypeIter<std::list<X>::iterator>` and `directedListTypeIter<std::list<X>::reverse_iterator>`.

Returning either kind from the same function is as possible as returning either a `list<int>` or a `vector<double>` from the same function. Given that your only use case is broken, I wonder what is your design objective.

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to provide an STL-style iterator interface from your class, there are basically two approaches. One is that you simply return iterators to the underlying containers. The other is that you wrap them somehow, for which there are helper, like e.g. the Boost.Iterator library. Then, to template all this, just replace the according type with the template parameter and sprinkle in a few `typename`s. That's all.

Comment: 1. My design works. all what doesn't works is what I written in question iii. This should be a shorter implementation. It correctly compiles and works in VS2012-express.
2. Now I reformatted the post. some1 redited my post incorrectly.
3. DyP- please read the p.s. in my original post. I mean- you probably right in your suggestion, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I am a little confused here.  If you've inherited `std::list<>::iterator` stuff, why are you redefining `operator=()` for the new class which just ends up delegating the call back to the base class?  As for `begin()`, there's all kinds of wrong there as people have explained before.  You do not have a single `directedListTypeIter` class; you have `directedListTypeIter : list::iterator` and `directedListTypeIter : list::reverse_iterator`.  The child class may have the same name, but the parents are completely different.